# Listeners for NavigationUI, set on NavigationViewOptions not working

Tags: mapbox-android

I'm using `mapbox-android-navigation` and `navigation-ui`, version 0.11.1, to display turn-by-turn for routes I'm creating.  Everything is working great, except I'm not getting callbacks from the navigation UI.

Specifically, I've set listeners on my NavigationViewOptions object as directed.  But the listeners never get called back.  Moreover, it appears like the listeners are being ignored if you follow the code into `NavigationLauncher#startNavigation`

Here is my code to launch turn-by-turn:

> private fun launchTurnByTurn() {
>
> ```
> val navigationListener = object: NavigationListener {
>     override fun onNavigationFinished() = Timber.i("onNavigationFinished()")
>     override fun onNavigationRunning() = Timber.i("onNavigationRunning()")
>     override fun onCancelNavigation() = Timber.i("onCancelNavigation()")
> }
>
> val routeListener = object: RouteListener {
>     override fun allowRerouteFrom(offRoutePoint: Point?): Boolean {
>         Timber.i("allowRerouteFrom()")
>         return true
>     }
>     override fun onFailedReroute(errorMessage: String?) = Timber.i("onFailedReroute()")
>     override fun onRerouteAlong(directionsRoute: DirectionsRoute?) = Timber.i("onRerouteAlong()")
>     override fun onOffRoute(offRoutePoint: Point?) = Timber.i("TC onOffRoute")
> }
>
> val simulateRoute = true
>
> // Create a NavigationViewOptions object to package everything together
> val options = NavigationViewOptions.builder()
>         .directionsRoute(routesMap?.currentRoute)
>         .shouldSimulateRoute(simulateRoute)
>         .navigationListener(navigationListener)
>         .routeListener(routeListener)
>         .build()
>
> NavigationLauncher.startNavigation(this, options)
> ```
>
> }

My question is, should these listeners be called, or has this callback feature just not been implemented yet?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to pass `NavigationViewOptions` into `NavigationLauncher.startNavigation` when it accepts `NavigationLauncherOptions`.

See the clarification here: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-navigation-android/issues/781#issuecomment-374328736